# Next.js removes trailing slashes in urls with a dot

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

We are moving our React project to Next.js framework.

We need to leave such urls /some-url-with-a.dot/ because thousands of pages in our project are indexed by search engines with trailing slashes.

But Next.js removes trailing slashes in urls with a dot considering it a file names with extensions.

There is no any setting in a Next.js config to manage this behavior (trailingSlash: true cause no any effect on this case).

The support know about this behavior and suggest to change dots to e. g. dashes.

I'm trying to examine the Next.js sources to solve this issue but without success yet.

Is there somebody who faced such a problem?